# Laravel Auth conditional redirect

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I used `php artisan make:auth` to create basic authentication system in my Laravel project.

On Homepage I created Bootstrap modal with login form, which works fine when I enter correct details, I get logged in and redirected back to Homepage.

But if I enter wrong details the page reloads and I dont see what was wrong because obviously the error messages are in modal window, which is hidden because page was just realoaded. And I have to open modal myself again to see the errors.

So I would like to edit my LoginController(or whatever) in case of errors(form validation fail) to redirect me to */login* URL where is the basic login form(without modal) to see the errors properly.

Comment: You can just fire a Jquery event to open the modal if you gets any error on view page by this way you can avoid the additional login page

Comment: Thank you, but that is the solution I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

In [`LoginController`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php) you can overwrite the default methods of [`AuthenticatesUsers`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php). For example you can overwrite the `sendFailedLoginResponse()` which handles the error when the username/email and password don't match:

```
/**
 * Get the failed login response instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')];

    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json($errors, 422);
    }

    return redirect()->to('/login')
        ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors($errors);
}
```

So the code above needs to be in the `app/Http/Auth/LoginController`. The code is the same as the default code, but redirects the user to `/login`.

**However** this doesn't work for form validation errors. Therefor you need to overwrite the [`validateLogin()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L59) method.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, I would suggest you use AJAX call to Laravel's auth routes. If the login is successful then redirect to home using Javascript or display the validation errors in the same login pop-up.

This is the best and recommended approach in such cases.

There are a lot of posts available over the internet. Just search AJAX login in Laravel.